# Magento Customer address missing when creating new order + new customer from backend

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, customer-address, address

Running on Magento 1.8

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create Order > Create New Customer
2. Add product
3. Fill in every mandatory field including address
4. Create Order
5. After Order is created, go to Manage Customer. From there you can
   see the customer address is blank.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think you missed some information in your question. My setup: 2 websites: DE and CH. In each website I configured allowed countried: in DE it is only DE, in CH it is only CH. I create an order in CH website and choose register as new client, fill-in CH as country. I go to backend, find new customer and see customer for CH website. In address of this customer I see empty required field country and only DE in the list of countries.

Comment: The solution to my problem is that allowed countries in standard configuration should include all countries.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, this is not magento core behavior, therefore not reproducible with such less informations.

I would assume it is some kind of observer which goes crazy and saves two times. But I have no clue, why the second is an insert too instead of an update.